# Single queue used by multiple projects

Tags: java, maven, queue

I have multiple(five) maven projects where I have to put the output in a single queue.All the output data from the different project should come in the same queue.How to do it?

Comment: What kind of queue are you talking about?

Comment: Simple Java Queue.Inside java.util.Collection;

Comment: In that case we'd need more information about the problem, best supported by an example. How you access a queue depends on your code and not the build system (e.g. Maven) you use.

Comment: All the projects are rest API's(5 of them).Having a URI for PUT,POST,GET and DELETE.All of them are accessing a common NOSQL DB. I need to put the response from DB into a common queue in all cases.Is it possible to do this. A tutotial or reference would help.Thanks.

Comment: I still don't get what you're after. Create an application that calls the others and collect the results into a single queue or let the projects submit their results to some application which maintains the queue. Or are you after JMS?